# How to disable the all network adaptor or interface into down state during the startup in MAC OSX

Tags: macos

I am new to MAC architecture. 
I need to disable all the network adaptors during the System startup.
I have no idea to solve.

Is it possible add the commands like

**sudo ifconfig en0 down; 
 sudo ifconfig en1 down**

into the startup scripts ?? or

it is best to write daemons ??

Please suggest me some good solutions to solve this problem ..

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Thanks Gordon**,

Finally I got a solution to my problem.

I used a bash script + plist,

#disable_internet.sh ( Executive Permission using chmod )

```
    #!/bin/sh
    sudo ifconfig en0 down > /dev/null 2>&1
```

#com.disable.interent.startup.plist

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
    <plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>com.symantec.disable.internet</string>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
            <string>/Users/Shared/disable_internet.sh</string>
        </array>
        <key>RunAtLoad</key>
        <true/>
        <key>OnDemand</key>
        <false/>
        <key>Nice</key>
        <integer>1</integer>
        <key>StartInterval</key>
        <integer>30</integer>
        <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
        <string>/dev/null</string>
        <key>StandardOutPath</key>
        <string>/dev/null</string>
    </dict>
    </plist>
```

##############
used a command:
##############

Before restart:

```
    sudo cp /Users/Shared/com.disable.interent.startup.plist /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.disable.interent.startup.plist

    sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.disable.interent.startup
```

---

After restart, when job is done:

```
    sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.disable.interent.startup

    sudo rm -rf /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.disable.interent.startup.plist

    sudo ifconfig en0 up
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to accomplish, so it's a bit hard to make solid recommendations. My understanding is that OS X's interfaces start off in the down state, then are configured & brought up by the `configd` daemon, based on the configuration in /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/*. So, I see several ways to do something along these lines:

- Configure the network settings to make all interfaces inactive (either in System Preferences -> Network pane, or with the `networksetup` command), and let `configd` apply them. Note that you'd have to make this change before shutting down in order for it to be the active config at startup.
- Somehow set the network config during startup before `configd` reads it. This is going to be very difficult, since OS X doesn't use a sequenced startup process; it just launches all of the various daemons, and lets them sort themselves out. Thus, trying to get your daemon to run before `configd` will be a crapshoot at best. (Actually, I can think of ways, but ... they're ugly.)
- Make another daemon that waits until `configd` activates the network interfaces, then turns them back off. And then watches to make sure `configd` doesn't turn them back on... Ick.

Basically, all of these approaches are problematic. But depending on what your [actual goal is](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem#66378), there might be a better way.